# popToRootViewControllerAnimated returning NSArray of "popped" VCs, but not calling viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently working on a project which implements a custom navigation controller, whose code is here:

https://gist.github.com/emilevictor/724a6602fedb8100650c

In one of my controllers, which gets pushed to the navigationController via a push segue, I have an action on a button to return to the main screen:

```
- (IBAction)returnToMainScreen:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *returnedControllers = [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Popped to root view controller."); 
}
```

This will return the current view controller and one preceding it in the returnedControllers array.

However, it doesn't change screens, or call any viewDidDisappear functions. Anyone know why?

Comment: You didn't call super in viewDidDisappear.

Comment: You need to dig into the custom code for this. The standard way it always calls necessary methods like viewDidDisappear.

Comment: From what I can see the custom code doesn't even override anything important - just rotation management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you child viewControllers are being added to the parent viewController with the method [UIViewController addChildViewController:]

Comment: On self.navigationController? I was under the impression that it happened automatically when performing a segue between the two screens. Is there a good tutorial or source of info that I can read that is better than the official documentation?

Comment: You say you are implementing a custom navigation controller, if you are overriding the methods (I presume you are subclass UINavigationController) where UINavigationController call addChildViewController: then this will cause your problem, are you overriding -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] for example. Its also the your navigationControllers parentViewController isn't set, jump in the debugger and look at childViewControllers.

Comment: OK, I will give this a go